# Redmine : How can other computers connect to my project on windows?

Tags: version-control, redmine, software-design, bitnami, infrastructure

I installed redmine by using bitnami and assigned people to project but assigned people can not connect the project. How can I connect host pc with the other computers from different locations over the web?

Comment: Users should be able to connect to Redmine using the Redmine URL. Provide more info about your question as it's not clear you want to know about access over the web or something else?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, if you are accessing Redmine from another computer in the same network, please use the private IP of the machine where Redmine is running to access the app. If you are accessing it from outside your network, you will need to configure the port forwarding rules in your router to redirect the requests to your public IP and port 80 to the machine where Redmine is installed.